Python nbtlib string to nbt?
How to format a string from "Compound({"foo": Int(123)})" to become a nbt Compound({"foo": Int(123)}), the parse_nbt can only understand from "{foo: 123}"
I tried to unpack() my compound to a string and then parse_nbt() my string but it mess with the tags, Byte and Long become Int f.e. and I need to be consistent about the tags
import nbtlib

Compound = nbtlib.Compound()
Compound["foo"] = nbtlib.Byte(1)
print(Compound)
>>> Compound({'foo': Byte(1)})
string = str(Compound.unpack())
print(string)
>>> {'foo': 1}
parsed = nbtlib.parse_nbt(string)
print(parsed)
>>> Compound({'foo': Int(1)})


you may have to create own function to format displayed string. later you maybe create own class - class MyCompound(nbtlib.Compound): and put your function to its def __str__(self): - and it will use it automatically when you will try to print object.

if you get string with external " then maybe simply strip "' from string -print( string.strip('"') )

Instead of Compound = nbtlib.Compound() you should use directly nbtlib.Compound
variable = eval( "nbtlib.Compound({'foo': Int(123)})" )`

Because it needs from nbtlib import Int so you can also use from nbtlib import Compound or even from nbtlib import *
from nbtlib import *

variable = eval( "Compound({'foo': Int(123)})" )

print(variable)

and if you have to create empty nbtlib.Compound() at start then don't use variable Compound for this.
from nbtlib import *

item = Compound()
item['foo'] = Byte(22)
print(item)
# Compound({'foo': Byte(22)})

text = str(item)

other = eval(text)
print(other)
# Compound({'foo': Byte(22)})
print(other['foo'])
# Byte(22)

